# Azure DevOps, How do you get timestamps from files uploaded to repos?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, timestamp, repository

Is there any way to get the last modified timestamps from files uploaded to folders in an ADO repo?

[ADO Repo Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg2Ni.png)

I have created a Python validation pipeline to check versioned file names in a folder in an Azure DevOps repo, and I was wondering if it was possible to get the last modified timestamp of the files so I know which are the latest.  I tried something like this (fileNames = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)) but ADO doesn't seem to actually save the modified timestamp like files might have on a local directory.  Is there any way to get this information?  I know I can see it in the GIT tree.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I know I can see it in the GIT tree." ? (I ask because Git doesn't actually store timestamps, so they get written on your machine to be the last time you checked them out.)

Comment: What is your goal here? The unit of change in Git is a **commit**, not individual files. You can see what files changed in a given commit, and the timestamp on when a commit was made.

Comment: So I can see a history of all of the commits made with timestamps.  I am trying to figure out how to programmatically extract these timestamps and the file(s) committed for each so I know what the latest files committed were.   I am using Flyway, and I am trying to make sure that the correct naming convention is being used by users.

Comment: You can start with the REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0